# How to properly turn WS Server to RXJS Api without Subjects in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, websocket, reactive-programming, rxjs

What's the proper way to turn the famous ws module into a reactive api in Node.js?
I understand that subjects can help with bridging non-reactive to reactive events, but their the problem is that they have a much harder time disposing their dependent objects.

```js
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });
var Rx = require('rx');  


var connectionMessageSubject = new Rx.Subject();

wss.on('connection', function connection(client) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    connectionMessageSubject.onNext({
      client: client,
      message: message
    });
  });
});
```

I can't use their built in fromEvent method because, it registers so many different events that NodeJS throws a warning when 30 or more clients connect.

For example...

```js
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port:8080});

var connectionMessageObservable;

//this uses a tremendous amount of memory and throws warnings that the event emitter has a maximum of 30 listeners 
wss.on('connection', function connection(client){
  connnectionMessageObservable = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(client, 'message');
});
```

Comment: Take a look at [Rx.DOM.fromWebSocket()](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/src/websocket.js).  You should be able to essentially clone that method and change it to work with the nodeJs ws module.  The pattern is implements is a good one to use.

Comment: FWIW, I rewrote a lot of fromWebSocket a little while ago. This pattern is a good pattern for wrapping something like WS in Node.

Comment: Also, I have a PR in for a `singleInstance` operator which *might* help for this scenario, if you find you have to publish().refCount() your ws wrapper and completely unsub it at times.

Answer (score 1):

The following code simulates the `subject` behavior.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port:8080});

var connectionMessage$ = new Rx.Observable(function (observer) {
    wss.on('connection', function connection(client){
        client.on('message', function (message){
            observer.next({
                client: client,
                message: message,
            })
        });
    });    
});

connectionMessage$.subscribe(function (cm) {
    // cm.client for client
    // cm.message for message
});
```